# Rails - Model Association on Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, models

I have models like that:

```
class Person
has_many :groups
has_many :group_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id"
end

class Group_Membership
belongs_to :member, :class_name => 'Person'
belongs_to :group
end

class Group
belongs_to :person
has_many :group_memberships
has_many :members, :class_name => "Person", :through => "group_memberships", :foreign_key => "member_id"
```

A person asks for a `membership`, creating a model of it with `status false`. The owner of the `group` on his `person#show` page can see who have asked for `membership` and also the `groups` he takes part. Since `groups` and `group_memberships` `belongs_to` a `person`, but `group_membership` also `belongs_to` a `group`, how can I make a view in `person#show` that allows the `person` to see who have asked for `memberships` on the `groups` the `person` own, and also what `groups` the `person` has a `membership`?

**##EDIT##**

The `status` here is `false` as default because a `person` will just be accepted in the `group` if the owner `edit` this status and set it as `true`.

Idea taken from this question: [Question about Association and Models on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038298/question-about-association-and-models-on-rails)

Comment: I don't see a relationship to define who has asked for a membership on a group...just who already has one...is this just a missing model or relationship. If I had this nugget of info I might be better able to answer your question.

Comment: That's where the status enters: if its false the membership has not been accepted yet. The owner of the group will accept the person on the group by updating the status to true, or reject by deleting the model.

Comment: oops. reading is my friend. sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some psuedo code that I think will get you on the path to what you want: https://gist.github.com/981513

```
class Person
    has_many :groups
    has_many :group_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id", :through => :groups

    scope :owned_groups, where(:is_owner => true).joins(:group_memberships) # gets all groups where this person is owner
end

class Group_Membership
    belongs_to :member, :class_name => 'Person'
    belongs_to :group

    # note that these attributes need to be defined
    # is_owner (boolean)
    # member_approved (boolean)

    scope :requested, :where(:member_approved => false)
end

class Group
    belongs_to :person
    has_many :group_memberships
    has_many :members, :class_name => "Person", :through => "group_memberships", :foreign_key => "member_id"
end
```

Fair warning, I haven't tested it at all, and I'm still learning the new AR patterns :)

I think that your group_memberships relation is probably a best fit as a :through relationship and then creating scopes around the different "states" that relationship can have. You might checkout [state machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) for some help on this too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well, I was thinking on something really simple... isn't there a way to reach my goal without making changes to the code and the database?

Comment: how does your current code know about the group owner and whether or not other members are approved relationships to that group?

Comment: The group_owner is known because Group has a FK named `person_id`. My idea on the relationship was just make a simple thing with the `status`, I don't care if the relation is always created on the model `group_membership`, my idea was to try filter it on the views and just show the ones with `status true` or something like this. I took this idea from another question from stack, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038298/question-about-association-and-models-on-rails

Comment: I was thinking that a Group could have many owners for some reason. I guess I don't read good. If you have a status column already, then you can just change the scope in the group_membership model to scope `:requested, :where(:status => 'approved')`

Answer (score 0):

I think like that

```
class Person
  has_many :groups
  has_many :group_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id"
  has_many :own_groups, :class_name => "Group", :through => "group_memberships", :foreign_key => "group_id"

end

class Group_Membership
  belongs_to :member, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :asked_group_memberships, :class_name => 'Group_Membership', :conditions => ['status = ?', false]
  has_many :members, :class_name => "Person", :through => "group_memberships", :foreign_key => "member_id", :conditions => ['group_memberships.status = ?', true]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The own_group thing is already done and it's working fine, via FK on group table (person_id). All I want is a way to make this owner of the group see all the group_memberships that exists to his group and accept or decline them.

Comment: What problem? `Person.first.groups.first.group_memberships`, no?